# Android - Restrict application installing on all user profile 6.0 when in development mode

Tags: android, android-user-profile

I am creating an app which is working fine only the problem is when I am installing/executing via Android studio it gets installed in all user profile. So my question is:-

> How can I restrict user to install/execute application to single user profile only while working in development environment.

The App is on **Google play store** also but from there when we install, it gets installed only to single user profile which is activated rite now. So how can we do it in development environment when we installing using Android studio.

> I have installed it using **ADB** also but its also installing to all user profile.

Comment: This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746422/how-to-use-adb-to-install-development-apps-for-one-user-only

Comment: That Quesiton is related to **ADB** only. I am asking about any of the method .

Comment: I'd be surprised if Android Studio doesn't use adb to install/launch your app. But it's not something I've verified.

Comment: Android Studio uses ADB to install/launch your app. Consider it verified @Michael

Comment: If I run/execute from android studio then I am not using **ADB**, its Android Studio which is using **ADB**. The link given by Michael is for using **ADB** only. What if I use Android Studio to run the app.

Comment: You and Android Studio have the same options available to you when you use adb. So if something isn't possible for you when you use adb directly, then it won't be possible for Android Studio when _it_ uses adb.

Comment: I agree but I am asking would it be possible using Android Studio or ADB. Because When installing app via ADB you can use `adb install your_apk_path` or `adb install -r your_apk_path`. Now you dont know when you use studio what it exactly using for installing apk.

Comment: Of course you do @Clairvoyant, it uses the `<rootFolder>/app/build/outputs/apk/<build variant name>`. So it's pretty safe to assume it's using the `adb install rootFolder/app/build/outputs/app_<flavor>_<build variant>.apk` to install. Such as `adb install myProject/app/build/outputs/app_release.apk`

Comment: What if application is already installed??? Then it should have to use `adb install -r apk_path_name`