# adb install apk file issue

Tags: android, adb, android-install-apk, android-debug

In Android phone, by default, there are two users, one is me, the other one is Guest.

I am doing Android app development. I install the debug mode apk by run command :

```
adb install myapp.apk
```

But when I uninstall it from :
Settings -> Apps -> (click into the app) Uninstall

the app is uninstalled but the app icon is still showing there & there is a text says it is uninstalled, if I `adb install myapp.apk` again now, the installation fails.

To get rid of this, I have to always switch to "Guest" user, and uninstall also from there. It is very annoying. Why `adb install myapp.apk` installs the APK on both users?

How can I only install the app in current user with `adb` so that when I uninstall it from settings it could be uninstalled completely without bothering me to switch to Guest user to uninstall again?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall via adb: `adb shell pm uninstall com.example.MyApp`

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/92130

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use \`adb\` to install development apps for one user only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746422/how-to-use-adb-to-install-development-apps-for-one-user-only)

Answer (score 1):

```
adb install -rf apk
```

This helps you in doing forceful re-installation